pandas formatting of cells is not applied in my jupyter notebook
I have the following python functions for formatting the cells of my dataframe when displayed in a html table:
def style_negative(v, color=''):
    return f"color: {color};" if v < 0 else None

display(HTML(df_GDP_Capita_Change
                 .style.map(style_negative, color='red')
                 .format('{:,.2%}', na_rep='-')
                 .set_caption('GDP per capita year change')
                 .to_html()))

When I apply this function to my dataframe, the output is like expected in my PyCharm IDE, but when I run the Jupyter notebook on the local host the formatting function is not applied to the table cells.
I really cannot figure out why this is and would appreciate if someone could point out why this is and how I could have the formatting also apply to the output on the local host page.
Output in PyCharm: 
Output Jupyter local host: 

I think you are overdoing the code in Jupyter that you are using. It shouldn't need the display(HTML( part or the .to_html() part. You don't include a minimal, reproducible example and so it is hard to give you a specific reply. (See How do I ask a good question? under 'Help others reproduce the problem' for next time or if you want to understand how you should have posted an MRE if you want verified specifics.) It looks like the example under 'Styler Functions' here is ...

 close to what you are trying to do. So follow that in Jupyter and then adapt it to yours.

Thanks for the advice about simplifying the statement.
The display is indeed not necessary, The HTML is, because otherwise I don't get a HTML rendering but the string with the HTML code.

I think the problem is due to the conda environment that PyCharm is using to run the Jupyter server. Probably one of the packages is missing or an older version is being used. With the huge amount of package is quite a job to find out which one it might be.
I installed Anaconda on my laptop and run Jupyter lab from that installation. From there everything is displaying nicely just like expected.
I think we can close the question.
